# Using Inno Setup, how to import a certificate .cer file?

Tags: installation, certificate, distribution, inno-setup

Can I use Inno Setup to import a `.cer` file (a certificate)?

How can I do it?

I need to create a certificate installer for Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Comment: I was thinking about using a command line with Certmgr.exe utility. Would it work with all windows system?

Comment: Certmgr.exe is not part of Windows, so you have to bundle it in your installer. I think it should work with all Windows releases, as it is part of Windows SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Certmgr.exe and yourcertificate.cer into setup:

```
[Files]
Source: CertMgr.exe; DestDir: {app}; Flags: deleteafterinstall
Source: yourcertificate.cer; DestDir: {app}; Flags: deleteafterinstall
```

And in [Run] section, write something like this:

```
Filename: {app}\CertMgr.exe; Parameters: "-add -all -c yourcertificate.cer -s -r localmachine trustedpublisher"; Flags: waituntilterminated runhidden;
```

Comment: In my case its self-signed certificate. so that line localmachine ended with root

Answer (score 17):

Actually the `CertMgr.exe` is not available on all PCs and furthermore it does not appear to be redistributable (as hinted by @TLama); and besides you don't even need it.

`CertUtil` is available on every Windows machine (that I have tested) and works perfectly:

```
[Run]
Filename: "certutil.exe"; Parameters: "-addstore ""TrustedPublisher"" {app}\MyCert.cer"; \
    StatusMsg: "Adding trusted publisher..."
```

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Admittedly I could have done more testing.  I only discovered this yesterday and so have not tested exhaustively; so far only on Win 10 machines.  But one is VM on Azure, 2 are regular PCs without visual studio, dotNets etc. (so no CertMgr.exe available), and then there is my DevPC which has CertMgr but CertUtil also works on it.

Comment: It is stated [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/09fb7a70-69c2-4cc0-ad82-173c06774261/availbility-of-certutil-on-different-windows-versions?forum=winserversecurity) that certutil.exe is shipped with Windows 7 and later. For earlier versions download it from [Microsoft download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c16ae515-c8f4-47ef-a1e4-a8dcbacff8e3&DisplayLang=en) ([ref](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/dde3925d-0376-4615-ac5e-61fae88f3da2/where-cound-i-download-certutilexe-and-certreqexe65311?forum=winservergen))

Comment: Nice solution. It's worth noting that calling certutil requires elevated privileges so this won't work for user profile installers.

Answer (score 3):

The reply by SlowLearner and Martin Prikryl is correct. However, a comment states the command requires elevated privileges. If you use the `-user` command it will access the user store therefore not requiring elevation:

```
[Run]
Filename: "certutil.exe"; Parameters: "-user -addstore ""Root"" {app}\MyCert.cer"; \
StatusMsg: "Adding root certificate..."
```